# Scilab cannot create Java Main-Class on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: scilab

First of all, I am sorry for asking this queston in askubuntu rather than in sciab community. But I need a fast solution and the sciab community can take a few days to answer a question.

I have a problem after installing scilab 5.5.2 on ubuntu 17.10. It says

[image: scilab 5.5.2 on ubuntu 17.10 crashed]

I tried to delete SCIHOME like many other suggest, but itu did not work. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: What graphics hardware / drivers does the computer have?

Comment: amd A10, Radeon

Comment: Hmm... possibly this bug? [Bug 1357 - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: XXX0 profile\[1\]: GL3bc -> profileImpl GL4bc !!! not mapped](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1357#c5)

Comment: mmm.. do you have any idea to fix this bug? Btw, thank you so much..

Comment: No I don't - sorry. I'm not sure your issue *is* that bug - but it sounds very similar.